# What does $NON-NLS-1$ mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse source code, I've found some '$NON-NLS-1$' in comments used like that :

```
private String toolTip = ""; //$NON-NLS-1$
```

What does that mean ?

Answer (score 391, accepted):

They silence a warning that Eclipse emits when it encounters string literals (and has been configured to complain).

The idea is that UI messages should not be embedded as string literals, but rather sourced from a resource file (so that they can be translated, proofed, etc). Consequently, Eclipse can be configured to detect string literals, so that you don't accidentally have leave unexternalized UI strings in the code; however, there are strings which should not be externalized (such as regexps) and so, //$NON-NLS-1$ gives you a way to communicate that fact to the compiler.

Comment: Ok, so, it is only on eclipse ? What about IntelliJ Idea or Netbeans ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware it's an Eclipse thing, though other IDEs may have picked it up.

Comment: So, what does NLS stand for?

Comment: @MatrixFrog it seems to be "National Language Support", at least that's what it's referred to here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906482.aspx

Comment: To be evaluative, I think such IDE-specific markers should not be used if code is altered in different environments. While the marker does no harm it clutters the code and makes it slightly more difficult to maintain.

Comment: So, how do you configure Eclipse to detect string literals, so that missing //$NON-NLS-1$ would raise a warning or smt?

Comment: NetBeans Platform uses //NOI18N comment keyword for the same purpose

Comment: @rpr To configure Eclipse to warn you about missing //$NON-NLS-1$, look under Window -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings.  It's below the Code Style dropdown.

Comment: I'm assuming `//$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$` just silences 3 strings in one line. Could you just put `//$NON-NLS$` to silence all string literals in a line?

Comment: @Matt Yes, you could.

Answer (score 61):

The string is not translatable. It tells the Eclipse editor to not flag the string as unresourced. This is important for multilingual applications.

Comment: Good explanation to why the flag is called NON NLS (No National Language Support). Thanks.

Answer (score 37):

`NON-NLS` means ***Non***-**N**ational **L**anguage **S**upport.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization#Naming) proposes also ***Non***-**N**ative **L**anguage **S**upport (NLS) but this last one is not very used.

**NLS** is about internationalizing your application. Eclipse help to locate hard-coded strings in your code. To indicate a string is not part of the internationalization, append the comment `//$NON-NLS-x$` where x is the position of the string. On the following example both `"!"` are hard-coded strings not part of the internationalization:

```
 public String foo(String key) { 
   return "!" + key + "!"; //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ 
 }
```

Notes:

- the leading `//` is necessary each time
- no global `$NON-NLS$` for multiple strings within the same line
  (e.g. if your line has six strings, you have to write six times `//$NON-NLS-x$`)

The book [EMF: Eclipse Modeling Framework at page 250](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ff-9ZYhvPwwC&pg=PA250) says:

> **Non-NLS Markers—** Eclipse's Java compiler has the ability to flag non-externalized strings as a warning or error, in order to facilitate enablement of National Language Support (NLS). EMF-generated code does not use hard coded strings for messages that the user will see; however, string literals do appear frequently, for example, as keys for lookup of externalized strings in a property file. This property controls whether to include comments that mark those literals as non-translatable, so that the compiler will not flag them.

For more details see also the pages [The Generator GUI](http://www.heod.ru/0131425420_ch11lev1sec2.shtml) and [How to Internationalize your Eclipse Plug-In](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Internationalization/how2I18n.html).

You can enable/disable this feature. On Eclipse Neon go to
`Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings`
and select the field
`Non-externalized strings (missing/unused $NON-NLS$ tag)`

[image: Window of the Project Properties on Eclipse]

Answer (score 14):

If you are an Android developer.  All strings the user may see should be in the resource file /res/values/strings.xml to read strings.xml file in the code you use R.string..  By adding the tag //$NON-NLS-$ you are noting that the string will not be seen by users.

The warning in Eclipse Helios may be turned on at `Window -> preferences -> java -> Compiler -> code style -> "Non-externalized Strings (missing/unused &NON-NLS$ tag)`.

If you are planning on programming your activity to be multi-language, it would be recommended to turn this on.  And then adding the &NON-NLS$ tag to strings that are internal to you activity.  Eclipse will add &NON-NLS$ tag in the quick-fix if you right click on the warning or error.

Answer (score 9):

It's used by Eclipse to indicate that a string doesn't need to be translated, probably because it's not going to be seen by the application's users.

Comment: Some strings don't work properly when they're translated. If a string represents a charset, HTML/XML tag, regex, etc., they could change the behaviour of the program.

Answer (score 5):

It tells the compiler not to complain about a non externalized string, and that it doesn't require localization.

Comment: I don't think it's the compiler, I think it's Eclipse that complains.

Comment: Eclipse has it's own compiler as part of JDT which it uses for this kind of thing. So yes it is the compiler (Eclipse's compiler anyway).

Answer (score 0):

It is an annotation that indicates that an annotated code element is a string which is not visible to users, which doesn’t require localization, and which doesn’t contain strings requiring localization. When you annotate an element with `NonNls`, localization tools will skip this element and strings inside it.