# What does the number after //$NON-NLS- mean

Tags: java, eclipse, internationalization

This is a follow up question to: [What does $NON-NLS-1$ mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654037)

I've noticed that the comment tag will be recognized as a NLS tag when you use any number. However, only the number 1 seems to correctly fixed the warning. (Silenced warning vs. unsilenced warning + unnecessary nls tag)

What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The number after `$NON-NLS-` signifies which string on the tagged line the tag is for. The number 1 works for you, likely because there is only 1 string on the line you are trying to tag.

If you had 2 strings on the same line, you can, for example, tag only the second string using `$NON-NLS-2$`.

```
//Warning on "baz"
foo("bar","baz"); //$NON-NLS-1$

//Warning on "bar"
foo("bar","baz"); //$NON-NLS-2$

//No warnings
foo("bar","baz"); //$NON-NLS-1$  //$NON-NLS-2$

//Warning on "baz" (apparently the slashes are required even with multiple tags)
foo("bar","baz"); //$NON-NLS-1$  $NON-NLS-2$
```

Comment: also if you want to suppress all string literal warnings you can use @SuppressWarnings("nls")